# Insert/ Update Scalability (searching increasingly longer list for update match untenable)

Tags: mysql, sql, scalability, insert-update

Haven't found a clear answer to this here.

I'm performing a basic "Insert/ Update' -- funneling new data into a MySQL database of "Tickets."

For example:

```
ticket_id: 154
status: open
messages: 2
```

That would be a ticket in the DB.

An incoming record would either insert/ update based on the ticket_id. Aka if the ticket_id is new, it will be inserted, if it's looked up and found, it will be updated. To possibly simplify this further, the ticket_ids are incremented sequentially in increasing order. ticket_id 1 is the first ticket ever, etc.

Here's my problem. Right now I'm insert/ updating against 100,000 ticket_ids in the DB. Each insert/update write (unlike a pure insert) -- has to lookup each incoming ID against 100,000 IDs to determine a potential match for update. Each month this will be increased by another 60,000 tickets ---- until eventually there are over 1,000,000 ticket_ids being "looked up" during each daily insert/ update. This is not scalable. In fact, it seems like it would be an extremely common issue for any regular insert/ update in a large MySQL database.

Here are the potential good things:

1. Ticket_IDs are unique and increase sequentially
2. Tickets become Status: Closed after 30 days of inactivity. This means they will never be updated again. This is the key here. I'm not sure how to technically "ignore" these tickets during an insert/ update without "looking up" them every day. One method would be to either daily, or monthly, transfer the "closed" tickets to a separate DB table, and use a union for database queries. Thoughts on this? I'm no DB admin by any means.

Is that the answer? 2 tables, and ticket archiving?

And also ... is there benefit to indexing Ticket_ID? I heard that increases write time, but decreases read time.

My problem right now, I think, is writing time for insert/ update, not SELECT statements. But one guy told me that insert/ update is essentially a SELECT/ lookup any way.

Comment: You probably already have an index on Ticket_id depending on how your table is set up. This will allow your table to increase to nearly any size with little change to the speed of your query. Not only that, but with the simplicity of your queries, read/write time should be negligible anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do is review the indices you already have

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table_name\G
```

If your UPSERTs are getting slower, adding an index to ticket_id is definitely a good place to start. I suggest that you make it a unique index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index_name my_table_name (ticket_id);
```

Adding indices does slow down INSERTs, but for a database with 60,000 new records per month, and 1,000,000 records in total, you probably won't notice.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like the index may help, but I'm not exactly certain how much. At the end of the day, there will still be an increasing log to 'look up' against --- unless index Ticket_ID will change a 10 minute write time to a matter of seconds or something of that magnitude. What about the two table idea? Wouldn't that surely cut down some work? Thanks

Comment: It is possible that an index could cut down a 10 minute query to a matter of seconds. While one can analyze these things theoretically, it is usually faster and more reliable to try it. As for two tables, that is a possibility. But for the amount of data you have, it is probably more work than it is worth.

Comment: It turns out a simple index (I think it's a B-tree, not sure the use cases for a hash table, seems better for direct equality comparisons) on a unique field 'Ticket ID' -- did cut down something that took 20 minutes to about 2 minutes. (This is 1000 rows against 250k). I'd still prefer that 1000 rows were update/ inserted even faster, but it's a great step forward. I may have to take a closer look at optimizing data types for each column as well, but yeah - didn't know indexes were that essential.